# JTAG Scripting: How can we structure like variable be used in JTAG scripting language

Tags: scripting, command, jtag, trace32

I am trying to access array of a structure like this (C equivalent)

```
Struct register
{
  int addr;
  int val;
}reg[100];

for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   Print reg[i].addr
```

How can this be achieved in Jtag scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the PRACTICE script language of the TRACE32 debugger from Lauterbach.

In the PRACTICE script language you can access any C/C++ language construct via the function `Var.VALUE(<hll-expression>)`, where *<hll-expression>* is any valid C/C++ expression returning a single value. (A hll-expression is bascially everything you can also display in the debuggers watch-window (`Var.Watch`)).

E.g.: If you'd like to access `val` from the 3rd element of your array `reg` you would use the expression `reg[2].val` in C. Thus in PRACTICE you'll do it like that:

```
PRVIATE &x                     // Create local macro on PRACTICE stack
&x=Var.VALUE(reg[2].val)       // Get element 'val' from 3rd element of 'reg'`
PRINT "Result: " %Decimal &x   // Print result to AREA window
```

To print all addresses of the whole array, write something like that:

```
Var.NEWLOCAL int \i=0  // Create artificial HLL variable on PRACTICE stack 
Var.WHILE \i<(sizeof(reg)/sizeof(reg[0]))
(
  PRINT %Decimal Var.VALUE(reg[\i].addr) 
  Var.ASSIGN \i++
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I will try this.